# Trigger Java method from USB Input Device

Tags: java, windows-7, usb, hid

I have purchased a USB big red button from [this](http://www.play-asia.com/USB_Big_Red_Button/paOS-13-71-134-49-en-70-41t9.html) site and I was wondering what the process would be to make that button trigger a function in my Java program.

It shows on the device manager as a "USB Input Device" under the "Human Interface Devices" section when i plug it in.